# POST method not called on servlet - GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets

I have this servlet to handle uploaded file and to store them on server.

```
public class ImageService extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 1GB

@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {

    slog("SERVLET STARTED");

    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {
        slog("REQUEST IS MULTIPART");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator<FileItem> iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                FileItem item = iterator.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    slog("TROVATO FILE " + item.getName());
                    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                    File path = new File(root + "/fileuploads");
                    slog("SALVO FILE IN " + path.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        path.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File uploadedFile = creaFileNonAmbiguo(path, fileName);
                    slog("NOME ASSEGNATO AL FILE " + uploadedFile.getName());
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                    response.getWriter()
                            .write(uploadedFile.getName() + ";");
                    files.add(uploadedFile.getName());
                }
            }

            response.getWriter().flush();
            slog("RISPOSTA INVIATA");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } else {
        slog("LA RICHIESTA NON E' MULTIPART");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }
    slog("SERVLET TERMINATA");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {

    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/").concat(
            "fileuploads/");
    String path = root.concat(request.getParameter("src"));

    File file = new File(path);
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private File creaFileNonAmbiguo(File path, String fileName) {

    File res = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
    if (!res.exists())
        return res;
    else {
        return creaFileNonAmbiguo(path, "c".concat(fileName));
    }
}

private void slog(String s) {
    System.out.println("UPLOAD SERVLET: " + s);
}

}
```

As you can see the servlet has doPost and doGet. doGet() is correctly called in this part of my code:

```
[...]
String path = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "imageUpload?src=";

    for (String foto : result) {
        String url = path.concat(foto);
[...]
```

But the doPost method is never called, as I can see from the Chrome debugger and from the fact that `SERVLET STARTED` is never logged.

This is the way I call the doPost() method from client:

```
inserisciSegnalazioneBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            if (!catLst.isEnabled()
                    || catLst.getItemText(catLst.getSelectedIndex())
                            .equals("")
                    || catLst.getItemText(catLst.getSelectedIndex())
                            .equals("")
                    || descrizioneBox.getText().equals("")
                    || gsb.getText().equals("")) {
                Window.alert("ATTENZIONE: devi riempire tutti i campi");
                return;
            }

            segnalazione.setCategoria(new Categoria(catLst.getItemText(catLst
                    .getSelectedIndex())));
            segnalazione.setDescrizione(descrizioneBox.getText());
            segnalazione.setIndirizzo(gsb.getText());
            segnalazione.setUtente(LoginPanel.username);

            Segnalazioni_Degrado.dataLayerService.inserisciSegnalazione(
                    segnalazione, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            caught.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                            if (result) {
                                geocode(segnalazione);
                                uploadFrm.submit();
                                Window.alert("Inserimento avvenuto con successo");
                                MenuPanel.refreshBtn.click();
                            } else
                                Window.alert("L'inserimento ha avuto esito negativo");
                            thisPnl.hide();
                        }

                    });

        }

    });

    uploadFrm.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "imageUpload");
    uploadFrm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    uploadFrm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

    uploadFrm
            .addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                    Window.alert("SUBMIT COMPLETATO");
                    String res = event.getResults();
                    if (res != null && !res.equals("")) {
                        Window.alert("IL SERVER RISPONDE " + res.toString());
                        String[] uploadedFiles = res.split(";");
                        aggiornaFotoDB(uploadedFiles, segnalazione);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The weird thing is that it works properly on DevMode, but it doesn't work when I deploy my webapp to Tomcat.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Make sure your servlet class is mapped properly in your `web.xml` file. Make sure `uploadFrm.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "imageUpload");` generates the same url pattern as in `web.xml`. You can see the "Network" tab on Chrome inspector or the "Net" tab in Firebug to see what happens when you submit your form. Make sure it doesn't result in 404 (or a server side error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was

```
thisPnl.hide();
```

The solution was to hide the panel INSIDE the `SubmitCompleteHandler`